# WebView can't load image android

Tags: android, webview

```
<img src='http://lt.ltcx.net.cn:109/upload/image/XheditorProjData/2013/10/18/31c314e0-a76a-4a72-8f9e-991d73a44990.jpg' alt='' />
```

I want to use webview to load the image,these is my code:

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    // 设置字符集编码
    mWebView.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("UTF-8");
    mWebView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(
            LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
    mWebView.getSettings().setBlockNetworkImage(false);
     mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
     mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, url, "text/html",
                "UTF-8", null);
```

but image can't display.I use HttpURLConnection to read binary stream to load this url, it works.I don't know why can't I load image by using webview.

Comment: I get this _This address uses a network port which is normally used for purposes other than Web browsing. Firefox has cancelled the request for your protection._ on Mozilla Firefox. Is it normal?

Comment: Have you specified in your Android manifest uses-permission with android.permission.INTERNET?

Comment: only IE allow to vist,our server forbid other web browsing.

Comment: thank you, I know the reason.

Answer (score 7):

You got the response in logcat below:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://' was loaded over HTTPS, 
                 but requested an insecure image.

Webview cannot load the images with http request after 
                 android KITKAT, so we have to set the websetting.
```

I paste the code below, hope you will solve the problem.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            webview.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(
                        WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
 }
```